# Xcode not responding when opening project and also creating new project

Tags: xcode

since a few days Xcode is giving me troubles. Without doing anything Xcode doesn't want to open any project of mine and doesn't even want to create a new project. It just doesn't respond so I also don't get a crash log.

**Steps I tried:**

1. Restart my Mac
2. Deleted Derived Data
3. Resetted all Xcode setting
4. Installes Xcode new

Nothing worked for me. Do you have any idea?

I have MacOS Ventura 13.4.1 and Xcode 14.3.1.

**Here is some part of my call graph as I can't get a crash log:**

Call graph: 2555 Thread_17792 DispatchQueue_97: IDEContainer - uniquing lock (serial) + 2555 start (in dyld) + 2236 [0x194dcbf28] + 2555 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit) + 880 [0x1983ec794] + 2555 -[DVTApplication run] (in DVTKit) + 60 [0x104d3ae08] + 2555 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit) + 500 [0x198415368] + 2555 -[NSApplication _handleEvent:] (in AppKit) + 60 [0x19879dfc4] + 2555 -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit) + 596 [0x10945646c] + 2555 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] (in AppKit) + 1556 [0x19854df0c] + 2555 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] (in AppKit) + 284 [0x19854ebc8] + 2555 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit) + 364 [0x19854ef08] + 2555 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit) + 3476 [0x1985c42cc] + 2555 -[DVTTableView mouseDown:] (in DVTUserInterfaceKit) + 140 [0x107964238] + 2555 -[NSTableView mouseDown:] (in AppKit) + 4132 [0x1986cf16c] + 2555 -[_NSBindingAdaptor objectDidTriggerDoubleClickAction:] (in AppKit) + 100 [0x198c29d4c] + 2555 -[NSActionBinder _performActionWithCommitEditing:didCommit:contextInfo:] (in AppKit) + 220 [0x19878df6c] + 2555 -[NSActionBinder _executePerformAction] (in AppKit) + 660 [0x19878de70] + 2555 -[NSActionBinder _invokeSelector:withArguments:forBinding:] (in AppKit) + 116 [0x19878db24] + 2555 -[NSBinder invokeSelector:withArguments:forBinding:error:] (in AppKit) + 140 [0x1987c1728] + 2555 -[NSBinder _invokeSelector:withArguments:onKeyPath:ofObject:mode:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:] (in AppKit) + 244 [0x1987c12cc] + 2555 CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation) + 96 [0x1951e29a0] + 2555 forwarding (in CoreFoundation) + 976 [0x1951e2e30] + 2555 -[NSInvocation invoke] (in CoreFoundation) + 428 [0x1951e4668] + 2555 invoking (in CoreFoundation) + 148 [0x1951e47f4] + 2555 -[NSObject(_NSBinderKeyValueCodingAdditions) _invokeSelector:withArguments:onKeyPath:] (in AppKit) + 620 [0x1988c6430] + 2555 -[IDEWelcomeWindowController openSelected:] (in IDEKit) + 444 [0x10945c8cc] + 2555 -[IDEWelcomeWindowController _openURL:completionHandler:] (in IDEKit) + 156 [0x10945c684] + 2555 -[IDEDocumentController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:] (in IDEKit) + 468 [0x10961a994] + 2555 -[IDEDocumentController _openDocumentsForDocumentLocations:display:externalParameters:completionHandler:] (in IDEKit) + 256 [0x10961a494] + 2555 -[IDEDocumentController _openProjectsPlaygroundsAndWorkspaces:display:externalParameters:completionHandler:] (in IDEKit) + 308 [0x109619a48] + 2555 -[IDEDocumentController _openProjectsPlaygroundsAndWorkspaces:display:openedDocuments:simpleFileDocumentLocations:externalParameters:completionHandler:] (in IDEKit) + 1228 [0x10961a148] + 2555 -[IDEDocumentController _openWrappingContainerDocument:displayDocument:completionHandler:] (in IDEKit) + 140 [0x109616ce8] +

Comment: If Xcode is hanging, take a diagnostic / sample and send it to Apple.

Comment: @matt How can I do that? Because I don't get a crash log because it doesn't crash

Comment: Did you read what I said? You don't send a crash log. You send a diagnostic / sample. This tells Apple what Xcode was doing during the hang.

Comment: And do you read what I wrote? I said how can I do that since I only know that method.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/guide/feedback-assistant/create-new-feedback-fbad45b5bb25/mac

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/